# how to handle 2 field types to one model field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have one model field some of its values are fontawsome icons ,others are image files how to handle 2 types in one field?
those list items are 2 different types , some are fontawsome icon links , others are image files, i need to put them in model field how?

```
     <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">

              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <i class="fab fa-js-square"></i>
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <i class="fab fa-sass"></i>
              </li>

              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <i class="fab fa-python"></i>
              </li>

              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img class="img-fluid img-profile  mx-auto mb-2" src="{% static 'img/sql.png' %}">
              </li>
              <li class="list-inline-item">
                <img id="logo" src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
              </li>
    </ul>
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

    from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

    from .models import *

    class homepage(TemplateView):
        template_name = "index.html"
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['About'] = About.objects.all()
            context['Experience'] = Experience.objects.order_by('date')
            return context
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models



    class About(models.Model):
        name         = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        address      = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        mobile       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        email        = models.EmailField(blank=True)
        description  = models.TextField()
        #interests   = models.TextFileld()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


    class Experience(models.Model):
        title    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        company  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        summery  = models.TextField()


        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

so i need to create skills model where i can add my skills

Comment: your code and wath are you really want ?

Comment: those list items are 2 different types , some are fontawsome icon links , others are image files, i need to put them in model field how?

Answer (score 0):

let me try to found what u need.

1-you have a template (html code that you write below your question ) , and you want access to inputted data in your backend in view or models?
2-you have a above template and you want to create model for it?

i haven't permission to add comment so i'm just leaved answer!

Comment: its exactly choise 2

Comment: great , now we found issue . tell us about your model.py . have you any model in your app or project? if you have model.py , view.py and teamplate.html  leave those code here by updating question.

Answer (score 0):

i  think in base view accessing to inputted value will be harder than a normal way . so its better use view .its simple and without any limit !

first u need add `<input>` tag in your `template.html` so user can input value in it and u can access to value in `view.py` . for best option use `<form>` tag and put `<input>` in it as many as you need.
something like this:

template.html:

```
<form action="user/new_user/" method="post" > 
   <input name="name_value"
   <input name="address_value">
   <input name="mobile_value">
   <input name="email_value">
   <input name="description_value"> 
   <button type=submit>submit form</button>
</form>

<div>
<p>{{message}}</p>
<p>{{boo}}</p>
</div>
```

when user pushing submit button page will going to `URL=user/new_user/` So add this url in `urls.py` :

```
import MyAppName.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/new_user/', MyAppName.views.AddUser),
]
```

above url will pass us to `function AddUser` in `views.py`. now we are in `views.py` and we want to access to `<input>`'s value here . all `<input>`'s value will be in `request` and we easily access to value just with `request.Post.get("name_of_input_tag")` :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def AddUser(request): # attention all def in views.py need "request" and its necessary .
     inputted_name = request.Post.get("name_value")
     inputted_address= request.Post.get("address_value")
     inputted_mobile= request.Post.get("mobile_value")
     inputted_email= request.Post.get("email_value")
     inputted_description = request.Post.get("description_value")
     #now we have all inputted values from template , so do what you want!

     #for example adding new "About"
     About.objects.create(
           name=inputted_name,
           address=inputted_address,
           mobile=inputted_mobile,
           email=inputted_email,
           description=inputted_description
           )
      # then we show some template with specific context
      context = {
      "message" : "new About created!",
      "boo" : "foo boo doo ",
      }
      return render {request , "template.html" ,context}
```

now you know how can input data in template and access to them in view . so for saving "skill" u can add new field in `experience`'s model and set value as u want in view.py by `request.Post.get("skill_value")`. don't forget use `<input>`'s name in `request.Post.get("input_name")`.

models.py :

```
class Experience(models.Model):
        title    = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        company  = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        date     = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
        summery  = models.TextField(,null=True,blank=True)
        skill = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)  # add this field
```